# I could not gather the response properly .When I put break points it is working properly but without break points it is not giving proper outcome

Tags: ios, closures

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let request = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().requestForQuery("SELECT Name,Id FROM Account where parentid='\(self.accountId)'");
    SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().sendRESTRequest(request, failBlock: {error in print(error)}, completeBlock: { responce in print(responce)
        self.dataRows = responce["records"] as! [NSDictionary]
        var counter = 0;
        for i in self.dataRows
        {
            let requestForGrandChilds = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().requestForQuery("select Name,Id from Account where parentid='\(i["Id"]!)'")
            SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().sendRESTRequest(requestForGrandChilds,
            failBlock:
            {
                error in print(error)
                print("error block")
            },
            completeBlock:
            {
                responceChild in
                self.grandChilds = responceChild["records"] as! [NSDictionary]
                self.dataOfGrandChilds["\(counter)"] = self.grandChilds
                print("id of parent \(i["Id"]!) and counter \(counter) and data \(self.dataOfGrandChilds["\(counter)"])")
                //print(self.dataOfGrandChilds)
                counter += 1
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                {
                    print("Control came to main queue")
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
                print("getting to know\(self.dataOfGrandChilds)")
            })
        }
    })
}
```

In the first request I'm trying fetch direct child accounts of an Id. In the completion block of 1st request I'm trying to fetch grand child accounts . dataRows is having data for section headers ( Which are direct child names). dataOfGrandChilds is dictionary that is holding section number as key and corresponding grandChilds array as its value.

When I put the break points at:

1. line number 10.SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().sendRESTRequest(requestForGrandChilds,
2. line number 23.counter += 1

the data in dataOfGrandChilds dictionary is properly setting and when remove the break points and execute the data in dataOfGrandschilds is setting inappropriately(i.e like for some other key,some other values is setting)

Please help me out.

Comment: You are issuing multiple asynchronous network operations at the same time. There is no guarantee as to which order they will complete and dictionaries are not thread safe, so corruption is almost assured. When you use the debugger you slow things down and force the operations to complete one at a time

Comment: Can you please suggest me the better way @Paulw11

Comment: @Paulw11,Hey I did it in a simpler way.
I send request for complete data and stored it in an array of dictionary and I filtered the data in a separate function. If you provide answer below I will be glad.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the **complete data** from ur database in `viewDidLoad()` and put that in `[NSDictionary]` type

then write code for **searching**